# How to use gradle in a java project (in Intellij) to switch between dev/release builds similar to Android Studio's assembleRelease/assembleDebug?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, gradle-plugin

Is there a gradle plugin for regular Java projects that adds additional build variants/tasks similar to Android Studio's assembleRelease/assembleDebug which use additional `src/release`, `src/debug` dirs that contain resources to override the default when building respective variant?

What am I needing is a way to use different configuration files for dev and release versions (sometimes even assets like some of the images are different). Is there some ready-to-use solution or I will have to define my custom task and add the copying of all needed files manually?

Answer (score 1):

you can implement similar to maven profiles behaviour, depending on the env property you could run specific gradle configuration (release or debug) like:

```
if (project.hasProperty('env') && project.getProperty('env') == 'prod') {
    apply from: 'gradle/production.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'gradle/development.gradle'
}
```

link: https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles

or overwrite particular task in similar manner:

build.gradle

```
task build(type: GradleBuild) {
    if (project.hasProperty('env') && project.getProperty('env') == 'prod') {
        buildFile = 'gradle/production.gradle'
    } else {
        buildFile = 'gradle/development.gradle'
    }
    tasks = ['hello']
}
```

development.gradle

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println "hello from the other build."
    }
}
```

link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_build